# Import class from other project with java always got an error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using eclipse Luna, maven 3.0.5 and Java 6. I'm working on 2 projects in eclipse.

Project A

```
package com.project.one;
public class Test{
  public String name="David";
}
```

Project B

```
package com.project.two;
import com.project.one.Test;
public class Hello{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println("Hello "+test.name);
    }
}
```

I add project A to project B using Build Path `(Right click on project B's folder in eclipse --> properties --> build path --> projects --> add)`, it's success but when the project B i compile using `mvn clean package` i got an error, and it said

```
BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] D:\xxx\Hello.java:[2,20] package package com.project.one does not exist
also line 5 and 6 is error (cannot find symbol)
```

So anyone can help me to resolve it?

Here's my workspace:
[image]

Comment: What are the location of the two packages relative to each other?  This sounds like Maven can't find the other project.

Comment: Project A and Project B are in the same workspace. Yeah maven can't find the project A. So do you know how to resolve this ?

Comment: Can you give a tree showing us the relationship between the two projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set maven dependencies explicilty. SO in projectB pom,xml you should explicilty mention your compile/run time dependency on project a

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project projectB. I 've added a jar file (Project A) into the libraries

Comment: You need to run mvn install on the project A first. Then run the mvn build on project B.  Mkae sure that the version ,artifact id and groupid values  are same as what you had provided in your projectA pom. In mvn you dont add  libraries exlpiclity.Rather you let mvn know where to look for the dependecnies